# pthreads-win32 2.10 pre-built lib/dll for x86 and x64

Tags: windows, pthreads-win32

I'm trying to find pre-built libs and dlls for pthreads-win32 v2.10 (a.k.a pthreads4w) for both x86 and x64, something similar to the ones existing for [v2.9.1](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release.zip)

The source code does exist in the [project's web-site](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/pthreads4w/ci/master/tree/) but the only pre-built version I could find is for [MinGW32](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/mingw/MinGW/Base/pthreads-w32/pthreads-w32-2.10-pre-20160821-1/pthreads-GC-w32-2.10-mingw32-pre-20160821-1-dev.tar.xz) which doesn't seem to have x64 dlls and libs.

Can anyone help me with this?